# keep elements of a list with certain conditions, Inferred type is not general enough

Tags: haskell

i am trying to keep from a list given only the numbers,chars, strings, bools etc that are greater or equal of i and less or equal of j. I also dont want to change my initial definition of Int->Int->[u]->[u] , some examples :

```
  >fromTo 3 7 [1..10]
   [3,4,5,6,7]
   >fromTo 1600 1600 [0..]
   [1599]
   > fromTo (-4) (-3) [False,True]
   []
   >fromTo 12 20 "Haskell"
   ""
   >fromTo (-4) 6 [0, 25..]
   [0,25,50,75,100,125]
```

here is with what i came up

```
fromTo :: Int->Int->[u]->[u]                         
fromTo i j list = filter2 i j (filter (\e1 -> e1>= i) list)     

filter2::Int->Int->[u]->[u]
filter2 y x filteredI = (filter (\e2 -> e2<= x) filteredI)
```

the error message is :

```
- Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : filter2
*** Expected type : Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
*** Inferred type : Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

Comment: how do you define comparison of Int values with any arbitrary type?

Comment: You can't write a function of that type that does this, so you'll have to change it somehow. Perhaps by constraining `u` with a typeclass that provides the comparison methods.

Comment: Did you mean: list given only the numbers,... that **have an index** greater or equal `i`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Int` to compare, so the `u` must also be `Int` in that case. Or you could make `i` and `j` more generic. Also you don't need two calls to `filter`. You could implement `fromTo` as follows

```
fromTo :: Ord a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
fromTo i j = filter (\x -> i <= x && x <= j)
```

then

```
fromTo (-4) 50 [0, 25..100]
[0,25,50]

fromTo 'c' 'x' ['a'..'z']
"cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx"
```